# How can I add a Range of cells as the body of a custom SMTP email from Excel using Visual Basic?

Tags: excel, vba, email, smtp

On the click of a button in Excel, I am sending a range of cells on a sheet as the body of an email. The email is sending correctly, but I cannot work out how to add the actual range of cells as the body. Here is the code I am currently using in Excel's Visual Basic along with the **Micrsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library**:

```
Sub Email_Figures_Click()
Dim myMail As CDO.Message

Set myMail = New CDO.Message

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "HIDDEN"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "HIDDEN"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "HIDDEN"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

With myMail
.Subject = "HIDDEN"
.From = "HIDDEN"
.To = "HIDDEN"

    Dim myRng As Range
    Set myRng = Nothing

    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set myRng = Sheets("Monthly Figures").Range("A1:B29").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If myRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub

    End If

.HTMLBody = myRng
End With
On Error Resume Next
myMail.Send
MsgBox ("Email has been sent!")
Set myMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Anything that has the word HIDDEN is to protect the client.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you cannot simply assign the range to `.HTMLBody`. You may have to construct the HTML-String "by hand" and have something similar to

```
html_text = "<table>" & vbCrLf & "<tr>"
For Each Row In myrng.Rows
    For Each cell In Row.Cells
        html_text = html_text & "<td>" & cell.Text & "</td>"
    Next cell
    html_text = html_text & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
Next Row
html_text = html_text & "</table>"
.HTMLBody=html_text
```

replace your line

```
.HTMLBody = myRng
```

.

Comment: Works perfectly. I just need to figure out how to add some formatting to the text now. Do you have any idea about this also?

Comment: You can use any HTML-markup, see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp) or many others for reference. Or you just format the mail in any mailing tool to look as it should do, export as html and change the definition of the `html_text` variable accordingly. One problem might be that the `<style>` tag will determine the mails appearance, but belongs to the HTML `<head>` section. As I have not found a proper reference for CDO, I dont know how to do that. You could try putting it at the very beginning of the `<body>` or including the styles as attributes of all the tags.

Comment: I added the HTML as you instructed, but I think I am not quite getting something correct as it presents a problem as soon as it gets to the second Next cell. I have changed part of the original code to this:

http://rextester.com/SEG14395

Comment: What you did cannot work because `next cell` is just the footer line of the loop. If you want to just go through an arbitrary collection of cells (what you were trying in the externally provided code sample, maybe you should provide it here; also, this was not what you tried in the original question), construct an array of Captions and one of Ranges (or Strings keeping the addresses) and loop through those. More flexible would be including the captions in the sheet and passing a coherent range like you did in the original question, though.

Comment: Ahh, I thought next cell actually moved to the next cell from the selected range. For example if I just paste Cell1 and then used Next Cell, then Cell2 would be paste. Guess I misunderstood. Hence my HTML between each cell being pasted etc and a new Next Cell haha. How do I pass a coherent range and keep the sheets style formatting though? Because not all fonts in the range are same colour for instance.